# "at" symbol is not working in everyplace

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have connected a Microsoft keyboard to my MacBook Pro 2019. Since doing this, the @ symbol is not appearing when pressed.

Case 1:

- With the integrated keyboard, in Chrome, VSCode or another text editors, or even here typing:
- Key combination: right option + q: nothing happens

Case 2:

- With the external keyboard, in Chrome, VSCode or another text editors, or even here typing:
- Key combination: right option + q: nothing happens

Case 3:

- With the integrated keyboard, Slack, Notes:
- Key combination: right option + q: @ <-- only that way works

Why I can't write at all the @ symbol with the external keyboard?
Why I just can write in some apps the @ symbol with the integrated keyboard?

This is the input source:
[image]

And this are the Modifier keys:

a) for integrated:
[image]

b) for external:
[image]

Note that I remapped the command/option in the USB keyboard, but with this keyboard there's no way I can write the @ symbol

Comment: Try Shift/2 or Shift/{ - that's where they are [physically] on most keyboards. Mac & Win often swap these two keys - see https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wxy6.png

Comment: Doesn't work. It's very weird, why on some apps works and in others don't. Actually I can see my arroba there in the Keyboard preview

Comment: is that Spanish? Spanish seems to have 2 on opt/G though Spanish ISO layout has it on opt/2 You can find it if you mash keys using the Keyboard Viewer in the language menu

Comment: Yes, it's spanish, but as I said, I tried with all combinations with command/option/shift, Q and 2, and it works ONLY in some places, but in others nothing happens, but with the integrated KB it works almost always

Comment: I only just noticed you said 'right option'. Windows keyboards do not have a right alt[opt] key, they have AltGr, which as far as a Mac is concerned is ctrl+opt & will not generate the same key output as just opt. eg on UK, opt 2 gives € but ctrl/opt/2 gives 2 again.

Comment: With the integrated keyboard, does Option Q work for all apple apps -- Mail, Notes, Safari, TextEdit, Pages, Messages?  You are doing Command key Q with the external one, right, since you remapped it?  If you go back to Option = Option, does the Left Option key and Q work with Apple apps?

Answer (score -1):

If you look on your keyboard, you should see the @ above one the keys, probably the number 2. Try the combination Shift + that number and see if that works.

Comment: presumably, if it was written on the keyboard itself, the user may have already noticed.

Comment: I assumed so, but I just wanted to be sure, like you said in your comments. My guess is that alt-q is a shortcut in those apps to add an @, but I could very easily be wrong. It also seems that the OP is familiar with this, but I wanted to post this to be sure.

Comment: What is printed on the keyboard doesn't matter.  The Input Source determines which key does what, and for MacOS Latin American the @ in on Option Q.